# More accurate timer for measuring external .exe runtime from Python?

Tags: c++, python, time

I am trying to use Python to grab return values from compiled C++ exe's (while timing them).

This is my Python code

```
import subprocess
import time

info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

t1 = time.clock()
h = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\test.exe"], startupinfo=info) 
h.communicate()
t2 = time.clock()-t1

print "Return Code:", h.returncode
print "Duration:", t2
```

This is the contents of test.cpp:

```
int main(){    
    return 1234;
}
```

This is the Python output

```
Return Code: 1234

Duration: 0.0438238265388
```

I feel like 43+ milliseconds is way too long and inaccurate. Is there a better way?

Comment: Consider running the executable multiple times, then dividing by the number of runs?

Comment: Using that method it seems to crunch down to 15 ms for 300 averaged runs... better but still seems too slow. My Python outputs are much faster than this and I know Python is loads slower than C++

Comment: Is there a way I can use the internal clock_t method in C++ and somehow get both the time and the return value from the program itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also suggest to measure the time from C++ program itself and if your are still interested in getting the time in Python program, you can return back the time calculated from C++ program which should be pretty much accurate. Also as others suggested, take an average of multiple runs.